# Wordpress: how to create a section with editable text in theme customization?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am experimantating with creating wordpress theme's.
In much pre made theme's you can edit text or other options for a section in the theme customize menu.
I did google a bit for it but my results weren't the ones I need.
Does anyone know how to reach this?

Comment: It is called theme options. Check **[WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)**

Comment: @ksno sorry, I started learning yesterday so my knowledge isn't verry big yet, thanks for your comment, that will help improve my google searches

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own theme option page. This link will help you

[https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages](http://Theme%20options)

Example code

```
 Creating a Theme Settings Page Menu Item
  function theme_settings_page(){}

  function add_theme_menu_item()
  {
   add_menu_page("Theme Panel", "Theme Panel", "manage_options", "theme panel", "theme_settings_page", null, 99);
  }

  add_action("admin_menu", "add_theme_menu_item");
```

Here is the code for the theme_settings_page function to create a section and add the submit button.

```
    function theme_settings_page()
    {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Theme Panel</h1>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
            settings_fields("section");
            do_settings_sections("theme-options");      
            submit_button(); 
        ?>          
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
     }
```

Uploading a Logo

```
    function logo_display()
     {
     ?>
    <input type="file" name="logo" /> 
    <?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>
```

```
function handle_logo_upload()
  {
if(!empty($_FILES["demo-file"]["tmp_name"]))
  {
    $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["logo"], array('test_form' => FALSE));
    $temp = $urls["url"];
    return $temp;   
}

  return $option;
   }

  function display_theme_panel_fields()
     {
   add_settings_section("section", "All Settings", null, "theme-options");

   add_settings_field("logo", "Logo", "logo_display", "theme-options", "section");  

   register_setting("section", "logo", "handle_logo_upload");
   }

    add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but this is something totally difrent.
My goal is to create new options in wp dashboard -> appeariance -> customize.

Comment: Nope isn't also what I ment, you have to do it with php and I already found it.
To add theme customize options you need to create a new section as I already mentioned this method is inside the $wp_customize variable.
near that you need to use the add_setting and add_control function.

Answer (score 0):

If you know CSS and Html just fallow the two steps

- Open the child theme style.css file in your text editor. (Or skip the
  FTP and text editor and just go to your WordPress admin area, 
  Appearance => Editor, and click on style.css on the right side).
- Open your site in Google Chrome, and open the Dev Tools (right-click
  and select “inspect element”).

If you dont aware about php, html, css etc. Follow the below link

[click me to customize wordpress](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/customize-theme.htm)

And Most of the Theme having Theme documentation you should follow the steps inside the theme documentation to change by theme options.